# How to import a MySQL db to OpenShift?

Tags: mysql, database, jsp, phpmyadmin, web-hosting

I've been working on a JSP project and now I want to host in on Openshift. Everything is set up except for the database. I already added MySQL 5.5 cartridge and phpMyAdmin 4.0 and I edited the credentials in my project as shown below. But how can I upload my database data to the application?

[Constants in my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXib6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the key was to replace the variables in the DB URL with [the openshift variables](https://developers.openshift.com/databases/mysql.html).

Answer (score 0):

To upload your data into your database you could use a tool to manage you tables (for example [Squirrel-SQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/)). To connect it with your openshift-database enable the port-forwarding through your rhc console so you can access the database as it would be a local one and connect to it through squirrel. (you cannot connect direcly to the remote database from openshift - only with port-forwarding)

```
rhc <app-name> port-forward
```